# Terraform WAF Web ACL Resource is useless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Terraform provides a [`WAF Web ACL Resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_byte_match_set.html#). Can it be attached to anything using terraform such as an ALB or is it useless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the release of the [1.12 AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1120-march-23-2018) it is now possible to directly create regional WAF resources for use with load balancers.

You can now create any of a [`aws_wafregional_byte_match_set`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_byte_match_set.html), [`aws_wafregional_ipset`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_ipset.html), [`aws_wafregional_size_constraint_set`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_size_constraint_set.html), [`aws_wafregional_sql_injection_match_set`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_sql_injection_match_set.html) or [`aws_wafregional_xss_match_set`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_xss_match_set.html), linking these to [`aws_wafregional_rule`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_rule.html) as predicates and then in turn adding the WAF rules to a [`aws_wafregional_web_acl`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_web_acl.html). Then finally you can attach the regional WAF to a load balancer with the [`aws_wafregional_web_acl_association` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_web_acl_association.html).

The Regional WAF Web ACL association resource docs give a helpful [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_web_acl_association.html#example-usage) of how they all link together:

```
resource "aws_wafregional_ipset" "ipset" {
  name = "tfIPSet"

  ip_set_descriptor {
    type  = "IPV4"
    value = "192.0.7.0/24"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_rule" "foo" {
  name        = "tfWAFRule"
  metric_name = "tfWAFRule"

  predicate {
    data_id = "${aws_wafregional_ipset.ipset.id}"
    negated = false
    type    = "IPMatch"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafregional_web_acl" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
  metric_name = "foo"
  default_action {
    type = "ALLOW"
  }
  rule {
    action {
      type = "BLOCK"
    }
    priority = 1
    rule_id = "${aws_wafregional_rule.foo.id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "foo" {
  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "foo" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.foo.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.1.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "bar" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.foo.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.1.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]}"
}

resource "aws_alb" "foo" {
  internal = true
  subnets = ["${aws_subnet.foo.id}", "${aws_subnet.bar.id}"]
}

resource "aws_wafregional_web_acl_association" "foo" {
  resource_arn = "${aws_alb.foo.arn}"
  web_acl_id = "${aws_wafregional_web_acl.foo.id}"
}
```

#### Original post:

The regional WAF resources have been caught up in a mixture of review and people abandoning pull requests but are scheduled for the [AWS provider 1.12.0 release](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/milestone/14).

Currently there are only [byte match set](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_byte_match_set.html) and [IP address set](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/wafregional_ipset.html) resources available so they're not much use without the rule, ACL and association resources to actually do things with.

Until then you could use CloudFormation with Terraform's own escape hatch [`aws_cloudformation_stack` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html) with something like this:

```
resource "aws_lb" "load_balancer" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "waf" {
  name = "waf-example"

  parameters {
    ALBArn = "${aws_lb.load_balancer.arn}"
  }

  template_body = <<STACK
Parameters:
  ALBArn:
    Type: String

Resources:
  WAF:
    Type: AWS::WAFRegional::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: WAF-Example
      DefaultAction:
        Type: BLOCK
      MetricName: WafExample
      Rules:
        - Action:
            Type: ALLOW
          Priority: 2
          RuleId:
            Ref: WhitelistRule

  WhitelistRule:
    Type: AWS::WAFRegional::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: WAF-Example-Whitelist
      MetricName: WafExampleWhiteList
      Predicates:
        - DataId:
            Ref: ExternalAPIURI
          Negated: false
          Type: ByteMatch

  ExternalAPIURI:
    Type: AWS::WAFRegional::ByteMatchSet
    Properties:
      Name: WAF-Example-StringMatch
      ByteMatchTuples:
        - FieldToMatch:
            Type: URI
          PositionalConstraint: STARTS_WITH
          TargetString: /public/
          TextTransformation: NONE

  WAFALBattachment:
    Type: AWS::WAFRegional::WebACLAssociation
    Properties:
      ResourceArn:
        Ref: ALBArn
      WebACLId:
        Ref: WAF
STACK
}
```